Determining analytic functions satisfying certain properties
I am interested in determining all analytic functions $f: H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on the half-plane $H=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re} z>0\}$ that satisfy $f(\sqrt{n})=n$ and $\left|f^{(n)}(1)\right| \leq 3$ for all positive integers $n$.
I noticed that if we define $g(z)=f(z)-z^2$, then $g(\sqrt{n})=0$ for all $n\ge 1$ and $\left|g^{(n)}(1)\right| \leq 5$. Furthermore, we can write
$$g(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{g^{(n)}(1)}{k!} (z-1)^k,$$
converging in a disk of radius $R$ for $1/R=\limsup_{k\to\infty} \frac{|g^{(n)}(1)|^{1/k}}{(k!)^{1/k}} |z-1|=0$. Hence, the series converges uniformly on any compact set and we can extend $g$ to an entire function. Noticing that
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}^{h+1}}$$
converges for $h>1$, we have that the genus of $g$ is at least $h=2$. If $\sqrt{\mathbb{N}}$ were the only zeros of $g$, we could write
$$g(z)=e^{\rho(z)}\prod_{n\ge 1} \left(1-\frac{z}{\sqrt{n}}\right) e^{\frac{z}{\sqrt{n}}+ \frac{1}{2} z^2/n}$$
with $\rho(z)$ is entire. What else can be said?

note that if $h(z)=g(z+1)=\sum c_nz^n$ then $|c_n|= |\frac{g^{(n)}(1)}{n!}| \le 5/n!$ so $\log 1/|c_n| \ge n\log n +o(n\log n)$ which gives by the standard formula for order in terms of coefficients that $h$ has order at most $1$ and that is not possible since $h$ has too many roots as noted so there is no such $f$

Thank you, I will accept this answer if you make it into one.

no problem - posted as answer

As requested let me expand my comment into an answer. With the OP notation, let $h(z)=g(z+1)=\sum c_nz^n$ and then by hypothesis $|c_n|= |\frac{g^{(n)}(1)}{n!}| \le 5/n!$ so $\log 1/|c_n| \ge n\log n +o(n\log n)$.
The standard formula for order of an entire function $\sum c_nz^n$ in terms of its coefficients $$\rho=\limsup \frac{n\log n}{-\log |c_n|}$$ gives $\rho(g)=\rho(h) \le 1$ so its genus is at most $1$.
But as noted in the post, $g$ has lots of roots that make it of genus at least $2$ and that is a contradiction so there is no such $g$ hence no such $f$.
